# Nodejs error when executing from Laravel using Symfony Process

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, symfony-process

I am trying to execute a `Nodejs` file from a `Laravel` controller using `Symfony` Process:

```
$process = new Process('node node/test.js');
$process->run();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

The `node/test.js` is located in the `Laravel public directory` and looks like this:

```
const scrapedin = require('scrapedin')
  const fs = require('fs')

  const cookies = fs.readFileSync('cookies.json')
  const options = {
    cookies: JSON.parse(cookies)
  }

  scrapedin(options)
.then((profileScraper) => profileScraper('https://www.linkedin.com/in/profile/'))
.then((profile) => console.log(profile))
```

When running this from `Laravel` I get the following error:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'scrapedin' at > > Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)

If I run the following command from the terminal the script will work fine:

```
node test.js
```

If I run the following command from the terminal I get the same error as above:

```
node /var/www/webste/public/node/test.js
```

I guess, from the `Laravel controller` I need to execute the `test.js` file that is saved in the root of the server and not the `test.js` file located in the `public/node` directory of the `Laravel app`. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

Comment: `require('./scrapedin');`?

Comment: Same error as above. I think it is still looking in the Laravel public directory when it needs to be looking for this file outside the Laravel app.

/usr/local/lib
└─┬ scrapedin@1.0.21

Comment: I think not, try to first go in to the directory where the script is e.g `/var/www/website/public/node/test.js` and try to run `node test.js` and I think it will work just fine. I think problem is that node is not resolving the paths correctly to your node_modules folder and so on.

Comment: I think you first need to change directory to the path where test.js i located or perhaps you could try doing something like `const scrapedin = require(__dirname + '/node_modules/scrapedin');`. I guess you could also install the package globally if possible `npm i -g scrapedin` which I think also would solve the problem. I think you will have a similar issue with the `cookies.json` file.

Comment: Does the `public/node` folder have a `node_modules` folder?

Comment: Tried just installing the package globally and using an absolute path does not work, so I guess you will need to actually install the package locally in the same folder as your script. Is this possible?

Comment: The public/node folder only contains the test.js file. The node_modules is located in the root directory of the server. I am able to install the package locally in the public/node folder. Just to clarify, it would only be the scraper package I am installing in this directory?

Comment: Quick side note that might be relevant: I had a similar issue running a Python script. Adding the following line to the top of the Python script resolved the issue: #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: const scrapedin = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapedin') and const cookies = fs.readFileSync('/usr/cookies.json') - moved cookies.json to usr directory - resolved the errors. However the output is appearing as string(0) ""

Comment: Yes if you install it locally then it would only be the scraper package since fs is a node core module.

Comment: It now works if I run node /var/www/website/public/node/test.js from terminal. When i try run it through Laravel the browser continues to load until it time outs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222927/discussion-between-cyclonecode-and-adam-winster).